# How to make text and URL link in one UIlabel in chat frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my chatting app. I have a UIlabel to show text inside chat frame. When user send text and URL weblink, I wanna show both text and URL link with UILabel like "LINE" app

[image: In LINE app]

So, Please help me to make text and URL link with one UILabel like "LINE" app.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  do you have code that shows what is not working?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and code. You may also have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After seeing Shibin's answer I realized you don't need to explicitly specify the range of the part of the string where the url is since it will be automatically detected, so I've commented that line out.

Also take a look at my blog post, [Text View Links](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/textview-links.html), for a complete example that also shows how to style the links as well.

---

What you are likely going to want to use is UITextView instead of UILabel so it can be clickable. UILabel can style it like a URL but doesn't support opening the URL. Below you can find the code for both label and a text view:

```
let urlString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "https://www.google.co.jp")
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Go to this website now: \(urlString.string)")

// attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: NSURL(string: urlString.string)!, range: NSMakeRange(24, urlString.length))

// text view
textView.dataDetectorTypes = .Link
textView.editable = false            
textView.attributedText = attributedString

// label
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Thank bro. I have used UITextView instead of UILabel. But I can't clickable on URL to go web
My UITextView inside cell of TableView. Help me, please.

Comment: @QuocTV I did a simple example inside a table view cell and it worked. You might want to start from scratch and compare what might be different. Check that the cell, contentView, and text view all have `userInteractionEnabled = true` and make sure the text view is a subview of the the cell's contentView w/ proper frame or constraints. And make sure nothing is overlaying it: `textView.superview.bringSubviewToFront(textView)`

Comment: @QuocTV You can also try giving your views noticeable background colors so you can see if something clear is overlapping it. I have a utility function that can turn all your views random ugly colors if it helps: [Ugly](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/ugly.html)

Comment: I have found the reason, super view of UItextView is very small. 
Korey Hinton, Thank bro man so much. You save my day

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you were able to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` and set `editable` property to `false`.

Use `dataDetectorTypes` to set whatever data to detect automatically. In your case, set `dataDetectorTypes` as `.Link`.

```
textView.editable = false 
textView.dataDetectorTypes = .Link
```