# How to make particular location is clickable in UiLabel in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having a `UITabelView` in that I'm having a `UILabel`. `UILabel` will be populated with different `text` contents with **one Email id**(all mail id's are same). I want to make this Email id clickable. So far I have done is I highlight this email id with **`blue colour`** and **underlined** it. I add a tap gesture to the `UILabel`,but it makes whole `UILabel` to be **clickable**. I want to make this email id is only clickable. Is there is any way to make this possible. I'm having custom table cell class,in that only I added **tap gesture**.

Comment: I agree with @BharatModi it will be easier to maintain.

Comment: Instead of take label and add gesture on label better way is take button it has clickable functionality and you can manage all the things that you want with label.

Comment: Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110460/how-to-make-text-and-url-link-in-one-uilabel-in-chat-frame) – you may use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` to make links work as needed.

Comment: But text view is showing only one line

Comment: @e.k You must be confusing it with `UITextField`. The `UITextView` is multiline ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview))

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`, And make sure add following, In your `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
<YourTableViewcell>.textView.editable = NO;
<YourTableViewcell>.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

The good thing is you need not handle the Email Click Actions, the UITextView will take care and open an email for you (with clicked an email, prepopulated in TO section).

Comment: No, I'm having more than 10 lines of contents. When I use text view means only one line is showing.

Comment: set [TextView setScrollEnabled:NO] and then adjust height from CGSize sizeThatFitsTextView = [TextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(TextView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)]; will solve your 1 line showing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TTAttributeLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) and which will be helpful detecting attributes and much more

Example for link detection :

```
TTTAttributedLabel *label = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink; // Automatically detect links when the label text is subsequently changed
label.delegate = self; // Delegate methods are called when the user taps on a link (see `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` protocol)

label.text = @"Fork me on GitHub! (https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked

NSRange range = [label.text rangeOfString:@"me"];
[label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range]; // Embedding a custom link in a substring
```

Following Delegate method is called when a link is detected.

```
// Delegate methods
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label
   didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
// Implement the code
}
```

Comment: Sorry,I don't want to use external library.

Comment: @e.k then use UITextView with dataDetectortypes.

Answer (score 0):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"String with a link" attributes:nil];
NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4); // for the word "link" in the string above
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.05 green:0.4 blue:0.65 alpha:1.0],  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) };

[attributedString setAttributes:linkAttributes range:linkRange];

// Assign attributedText to UILabel
customCell.bodyLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
customCell.bodyLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[customCell.bodyLabel addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnLabel:)]];


- (void)handleTapOnLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)tapGesture.view;
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeZero];
    NSString *string = [label text];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:nil];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];

// Configure layoutManager and textStorage

   [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
   [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

// Configure textContainer

   textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
   textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode;
   textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines;

   CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [tapGesture locationInView:tapGesture.view];
   CGSize labelSize = tapGesture.view.bounds.size;
   CGRect textBoundingBox = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
   CGPoint textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);

   CGPoint locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
   NSInteger indexOfCharacter = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInTextContainer inTextContainer:textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];

   NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4); // it's better to save the range somewhere when it was originally used for marking link in attributed string

   if (NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, linkRange)) {

    // Open an URL, or handle the tap on the link in any other way

      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"]];
   }
}
```